# How do I keep a horizontal column of divs in the same row when it is extends past the screen?

Tags: css

I'm having trouble keeping several divs in the same (horizontal) column. I tried the display: inline-block; css code, and it works until the divs extend past the screen horizontally. Then the divs that go out of the screen return to the next column down. How do I make the divs stay on the same column, even if they extend out of the screen? Is there a line of css code that forces all of the divs to stay in the same horizontal column? I haven't been able to find an answer to this yet so thanks for any help! :)

Comment: code please... probably a fiddle will be better to review

Comment: @Airwind711
<html>
 <body>
  <div style='background: cyan; height: 100px; width: 500px; display: inline-block;'></div>
  <div style='background: cyan; height: 100px; width: 500px; display: inline-block;'></div>
  <div style='background: cyan; height: 100px; width: 500px; display: inline-block;'></div>
  <div style='background: cyan; height: 100px; width: 500px; display: inline-block;'></div>
 </body>
</html>
All 4 divs have the same style.

Comment: Refer this similar one, let me know if it helps, usage of float & clear will suffice your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783374/4-column-div-layout

Comment: I tried using clear: both; to the css, but that just made the divs align vertically... display: inline-block; almost works, but some of the divs return to the next column so that they won't extend out of the screen. I want the all divs to stay on the same column no matter how many there are.

Comment: I found a simi solution. If the divs are a child of a parent div that has a width that is greater than the width of all the child divs combined, then all of the child divs will stay in the same collumn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try table layout.

`table-layout: fixed;` makes all column equal width.

```css
.outer{
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
.outer div[class*="col"]{
display: table-cell;
padding: 20px;
}
.col1{ background: red;}
.col2{ background: blue;}
.col3{ background: yellow;}
.col4{ background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="col1">
    column1 
</div>
<div class="col2">
    column2
</div>
<div class="col3">
    column3 
</div>
<div class="col4">
    column4 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @afelixj! What would happen if you made a column5?

Comment: Would column 5 return down and be right below column1?

Comment: you can experiment with this code in a fiddle - [https://jsfiddle.net/tyakgLr2/](https://jsfiddle.net/tyakgLr2/)

Comment: I messed around with it on a fiddle and you did something really cool but it wasn't exactly the answer to my question. I want the divs to extend outside of the screen and stay on the same column. To where you have to scroll to the right to see all of the divs. I don't want them to be squeezed inside the screen.

Comment: You can use an outer wrap and use `white-space: nowrap;` - [https://jsfiddle.net/tyakgLr2/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/tyakgLr2/1/)